# Jenkins - send credentials from pipeline to library's method

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, credentials

I want to get Jira issue changelog from API. I have pipeline which imports shared library and call method which is responsible for getting some data from api. My problem is that to get this data I need to authorize, so I want to pass user and password to this method. At this moment it looks like this:

Jenkins pipeline

```
def getJiraIssueTransition() {
    def credentials = credentials("jira-test")
    issueChangelog(credentials.username, credentials.password)
}
...

    stages {
        stage('Hello World') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello, World!'
                sleep 10
                getJiraIssueTransition()
            }
        }
    }
```

`issueChangelog` is a method from shared library and looks like that:

```
def call(String username, String password) {
    echo "im in pipeline library"
    def url = "https://MY-JIRA/rest/api/2/issue/MY-TASK?expand=changelog"
    def auth = "${username}:${password}"
    def headers = [Accept: "application/json"]

    def response = sh(script: """
    curl -u $auth -H 'Accept: ${headers.Accept}' $url
    """, returnStdout: true).trim()

    def data = readJSON text: response

    for (def d : data.changelog.histories) {
        for (def item : d.items) {
            if (item.toString == "In Progress") {
                echo "Created: ${d.created}"
                echo "${d}"
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting: `Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: d32fc5ae-9e4c-493a-8ae4-6b8b88a1cd72 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such field found: field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.UninstantiatedDescribableWithInterpolation username`

The credentials `jira-test` are `Username with password` type.

And I have problem to understand this error. Should I pass this credentials in different way or the whole process is broken?